# working with test data in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm learning winforms and I'm wonder is it possible to work with some test data like in unit tests that on every startup of aplication dummy data load and work with them for simple crud operations?

Thanks

Comment: You mean initialise the state of your application for automated tests? Almost certainly. How are you storing your application state? You could also code in an 'import state from file' command line option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/). But you will have to create a separate test data layer. I have been using this for quite a while now. Really good for mockup/dummy screens where some random data is required.